# Регистрация и авторизация через VK API

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api, авторизация, соцсети

Пытаюсь реализовать регистрацию/авторизацию на своём сайте через соц. сеть. 
Не совсем понятен принцип работы и дальнейшая безопасность после авторизации.

Изучил всё что тут написано: https://vk.com/dev/openapi

Создал приложение, добавил JS VK к себе, добавил тот скрипт, что там прописан. Соединение проходит, возвращается ID, имя и т.д. (всё что запрошу). Но как мне записать что-нибудь в БД, чтобы потом определить, что этот пользователь зарегистрирован/авторизован? Никакого хэша, который я бы мог использовать в этих целях, не возвращается.

Конечно, я могу после авторизации и получения ответа через JS, отправить AJAX-запрос к себе на сервер с ответом, который вернул ВК, но как проверить со стороны сервера, что авторизация прошла успешно и это не злоумышленник подсунул левый ID?

Хочется сделать именно асинхронную авторизацию, чтобы после клика на кнопку проверились данные и прошла авторизация/регистрация, и при этом она была бы безопасной.

---

Смотрел серию уроков [«PHP » Аутентификация через ВКонтакте»](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1659) и читал другие темы по этим вопросам, но, в основном, везде рассматривается синхронная авторизация, где пользователь будет несколько раз перенаправлен на другие страницы сайта, а мне такой вариант не подходит. Допускаю только одно обновление страницы пользователя: только тогда, когда он уже авторизован/зарегистрирован. Всё остальное — в асинхронном режиме.

Опять же, могу отправить ID пользователя к себе на сервер в свой скрипт, но как проверить его? Ведь у меня не будет параметра `code`, как в примере по ссылке выше и, соответственно, я не смогу отправить запрос для получения `access_token`.

---

Поправка: параметр `code` нашёл, а вот параметра `redirect_uri` — нет, и VK отвечает так:

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code
>   is invalid or expired."}

Делаю запрос так:

> $params = array(
>     'client_id' => 'тут ид моего приложения',
>
> 'client_secret' => 'тут ключ моего приложения',
>
> 'code' => $_POST['user']['sid'],
>
> 'redirect_uri' => '');
>
> $token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);

---

Понял, что процедуры серверного получения `code` не избежать. Начал делать по этим инструкциям: https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites

Предварительно всё равно провожу клиентскую авторизацию и только при успехе отправляю запрос на сервер, который затем отправляет запрос для получения переменной `code`, но опять вылазит окно с требованием ввести логин/пароль VK (на этот раз его требует серверная авторизация), а не нормальный ответ. В качестве `redirect_uri` указываю адрес вызываемого AJAX-файла, надеясь, что сервер VK вернёт туда `$_GET['code']`, и следующем запросом я смогу уже получить `access_token`...

Я так понимаю, окно с повторной авторизацией вылазит потому, что идёт проверка IP, которые не совпадают. Как быть?

Не понимаю, почему бы не сделать один и тот же `code`-ключ при клиентской авторизации и при серверной, чтобы можно было связать воедино и добиться-таки доступа в одно обновление страницы пользователя (с вылезающем окном VK, это ничего), но не 3-4 редиректа, как предлагается при полностью серверной авторизации в документации. Или, может, что-то делаю не так (что вероятнее).

---

Начал в PHP-файле делать так:

> if (!isset($_GET['code']))
>
> header('location:
>   http://oauth.vk.com/authorize' . '?' .
>   urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
>
> else echo $_GET['code'];

Теперь возвращается `code` при прямом открытии PHP-файла, а если он вызывается AJAX`ом, то там, понятное дело, ошибка после редиректа:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://oauth.vk.com/authorize...

Попытка использовать cURL или `file_get_contents` приводит к тому, что возвращается форма авторизации ВК и начинает "скакать" в прямом смысле слова на экране.

Эх :( Продолжаю разбираться. Может есть способ отправить запрос VK, но чтобы тот не редиректил назад, а вернул только ответ? (без `redirect_uri` сразу возращает ошибку)

---

**UPD**

Разобрался почти со всем самостоятельно: пришлось отказаться от авторизации "в один клик" и смириться с неизбежным — двумя редиректами сначала за `code`, а потом за `access_token`. Теперь другая проблема — как разлогинить приложение у пользователя?

А то получается, после одного подтверждения пользователем всё сохраняется и больше пользователя уже никто не спрашивает, разрешает ли он доступ сайта к данным, или нет. С одной стороны — это удобно, но с другой — у пользователя ведь может быть несколько учётных записей VK, или за одним компьютером могут сидеть несколько человек.

Поэтому нужно дать возможность разлогинить приложение у пользователя, например, при переходе по ссылке. Как я понял, это делается по ссылке

[http://oauth.vk.com/logout?client_id=ид_приложения](http://oauth.vk.com/logout?client_id=%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Но там ещё требует хэш, который непонятно откуда брать: в документации ни слова про разлогин. Техподдержка вконтакте молчит. Может хоть тут помогут?
Я пытался по-всякому передавать туда и `code`-переменную из авторизации, и `access_token` — толку нет, всё время:

> **wrong logout hash**

Comment: Есть вариант авторизации без тысячи редиректов. Это прямая авторизация. Там просто пользователь вводит свой лог и пасс и входит на сайт. Но есть одно ОООЧЕНЬ большое НО(!!!). Чтобы это сделать, нужно хорошенько попросить разрабов вк разрешить вам это. Они не очень охотно на это идут. Но если предоставить веские доводы почему ваш сайт/приложение будет выгодно и удобно, то в полне могут дать доступ.

Answer (score 5):

Сохраняете авторизацию в сессию, далее просто `unlink($_SESSION['Имя сессии']);`, всё пользователь разлогинен!

Comment: Поддерживаю метод  с сессией. Это, в принципе, самый правильный способ. Никаких хэшей от ВК вы не получите чтоб иначе разлогинить. Да это и н ни к чему. Ведь работаете вы уже на своем сайте через апи. Следовательно если нет значении в сессии  у вас - значит всё - ушел, до свиданья